# Geographical proximity based IP translation

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, anycast

I'm currently using Amazon's EC2 for my socket application to which mobile devices connect via an application I've written (it uses the server's IP address to connect).

I'm looking for a Load Balancing service, that will translate an IP address to a different IP address based on **Geographical proximity**.

For example, let's say I have to EC2 instances, one in Paris and one in NY, with the IPs 1.1.1.1 and 1.1.1.2 respectively.
Now I wish that if a user opens his mobile device (in NY) **and tries to connect to 1.1.1.0** he will be redirected to 1.1.1.1.

If pure geographical proximity based redirection too hard to implement, I may as well use latency based redirection. As far as I understand, only having instances in different continents will yield the same results (am I right?)

In any case, I have no clue of how to implement either one of them.
Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find so many IP based redirection tools and also they provide DB which you have to install on your server .

```
  http://www.ip2location.com/databases/db1-ip-country
```

Answer (score 0):

> If pure geographical proximity based redirection too hard to
>   implement, I may as well use latency based redirection

These are different things that sometimes mean the same thing. Proximity doesn't imply latency.

> As far as I understand, only having instances in different continents
>   will yield the same results (am I right?)

That solely depends on your application. If you have a shared back-end or a master to master
replication ,and so on. If everything is static yes it will be the same.

A couple solutions that spring to mind.
1. Content Delivery Network
2. Geo IP databases
3. Latency based routing

If you specifically want Geographical proximity then you can get your hands on an IP/location database , resolve and redirect from there. Their accuracy fluctuates a lot.